# How to convert serial datatype of postresql in c#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, type-conversion

I am using C# to read data from postgresql database. Data type of `Primary key` in postgresql is `serial` or `bigserial`. How can I convert into C# data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SERIAL` and `BIGSERIAL` are simply integer types.

`SERIAL` is `INT4`/`INT` and `BIGSERIAL` is `INT8`/`BIGINT`

By using `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` you are not only defining the type as `INT` or `BIGINT`, but you are telling PostgreSQL to also create a `SEQUENCE`.

How to verify:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sandbox.serial_test;
CREATE TABLE sandbox.serial_test
(
my_serial SERIAL,
my_big_serial BIGSERIAL
);

SELECT
  col.attname AS column_name,
  typ.typname AS type_name
FROM
  pg_class tbl
JOIN
  pg_attribute col
  ON  (col.attrelid = tbl.oid)
JOIN
  pg_type typ
  ON  (typ.oid = col.atttypid)
WHERE
  tbl.relname = 'serial_test' AND
  col.attname LIKE '%serial';
```

Result:

[image]

Reference to docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Thank you my brother. Do you have information about connection between Postgresql and ASP.NET

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485113/how-retrieve-a-multiple-images-from-postgresql-using-asp-net-with-c

Comment: Are you looking for a library to allow you to connect to a PostgreSQL database?: http://www.npgsql.org/  - Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I added `Npgsql.dll` to `bin` folder and add like reference. In addition I wrote connection string in `web.config`. But I do not know, what is it write in `*.aspx` file?

Comment: @Sawa - There is an example provided in that link: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html